# Error -52 bad filename or number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to check if the file at a given path exists. I did this…

```
Path1 = ws.[B3]
If Len(Dir(Path1)) = 0 Then
   msgbox "File does not exist"
   exit sub
end if
```

This code fails with an error -52 when the path contains a drive letter that is not active. For instance, my machine re-labeled what was the F drive as the E drive when I moved some USB keys. Any path referring to F causes error -52.

Can someone suggest a more robust method for checking for a file that won't fail in these cases?

Comment: I don't see that error when using a non-mapped drive letter.

Comment: I tried it with every possible drive letters (A-Z) and I don't have 26 mounted drives :)  `Len()` always returned 0 if drive letter did not exist --> no error. **Edit:** except for my DVD drive (D:) that did throw error 52.

Comment: interesting… did you try with different letters pointed to otherwise valid or invalid files?

Comment: With `Dir`, if the file is "invalid" it will just return string "".  Since it didn't work with my DVD drive, maybe a network drive that is disconnected but still in the drive list would also throw error 52.

Comment: If you still get errors on some paths, the solution would be to use an error handler to trap those errors.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it did not throw any errors even for my DVD drive (see my comment under OP's question):

```
Sub drives()

    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 25
        'This will print "True" or "False" in immediate window (Ctrl-G)
        Debug.Print FS.FileExists(Chr(65 + i) & ":\Filename.txt")
    Next i

End Sub
```